# Can't manage to set up environment and path to libraries under Visual studio for c++

Tags: c++, mongodb, gcc, visual-studio-code, include

After having installed the MongoDB drivers for c++ following [this tutorial](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/), I wrote a little bit of code that I managed to compile and run with the command:

`c++ --std=c++11 main.cpp -o app $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx) && D_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./app`

Now, I try to debug and launch my code with Visual code. I don't use Neither Visual studio because I'm under Linux nor NetBeans because I don't have the proper JDK nor Code::Blocks because it is too complicated to set up with the proper environment.

My problem is that Visual Code can't manage to find the several `#include` I need to work with MongoDB and Bsoncxx:[image]

I tried setting up a `launch.json` file with the parameter

```
"environment": [
                {
                    "name": "LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
                    "value": "/usr/local/lib"
                }
               ]
```

But I'm sure I'm doing totally wrong and I can't manage to find any solution over the internet. I could continue to write code then compile and run it via Batch files but an IDE is way more convenient.

Comment: Vs code isn’t an IDE. Your best bet is to create a task to run a ‘make’ file for you from within vscode. There are a lot of tutorials online to do it. For the includes though let me jump on my laptop and I’ll show you where to enter those to get intellisense working

Comment: Yes, I said IDE by abuse of language. Are you talking about a Makefile?  If I make one, would Visual Studio Code be able to refer to the correct location of the libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `Intellisense` working you'll need to tell Vscode where your `includes` are. To do this, do the following:

1. Install the `C/C++` extension for VSCode
2. Enter your include paths to in `c_cpp_properties.json`

Here is an example of the `c_cpp_properties.json` file I've used for a small project on `WSL`.

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${workspaceFolder}/deps/fmt/include/",
            "${workspaceFolder}/deps/spdlog/include/",
            "${workspaceFolder}/deps/CLI11/include/",
            "${workspaceFolder}/deps/pugixml/include/"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Follow this link for a full tutorial on how to set this up. [How to set up VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)

Pay special attention to the `Configure the compiler path` section and the `Create a build task` sections

Comment: Thank you, I managed to find the file and change the includePath parameter to match my libraries.